# sending automatic javamail from a website using java mail API

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

Below is my code for sending an automatic mail on registration from my website:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class ConfirmationMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int id=0;
        String passWord=null;
        sendMail(id, passWord);
    }

        public static void sendMail(int id, String passWord) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final String username = "xxx@gmail.com";
        final String password = "xxx";
        final String host= "smtp.gmail.com";
        final int port=587;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");


        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxx@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("xxxx@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Message sent successfully");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And when i run this on my eclipse its throwing exception the stack trace is as below:

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;  
  nested exception is:  
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?  
    at com.affiliate.DTO.ConfirmationMail.sendMail(ConfirmationMail.java:64)  
    at com.affiliate.servlet.AffiliateApproveServlet.doGet(AffiliateApproveServlet.java:39)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)  
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)  
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)  
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)  
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)  
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)  
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)  
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;  
  nested exception is:  
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?  
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1986)  
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:656)  
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)  
    at com.affiliate.DTO.ConfirmationMail.sendMail(ConfirmationMail.java:55)  
    ... 22 more  
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?  
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)  
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)  
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)  
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)  
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)  
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)  
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:532)  
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:337)  
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)  
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1950)  
    ... 25 more
```

And the jar files i have in my eclipse build path are javax.mail.jar , activation.jar, commons-email-1.0.jar
Please help me resolve this... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Which javamail version are you using? It should work with javamail 1.5.1, on older versions tls connection may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank u all for the tremendous effort put on solving this.... It helped me a lot... I resolved this by adding another line of coding as :

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
```

thank u all once again

Answer (score 3):

Use javamail 1.5.1

TLS connections work with this version. https://javamail.java.net/docs/SSLNOTES.txt

Replace

```
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```

with because gmail use TLS.

```
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Replace 4 lines below

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
transport.connect (host, port,username,password);
transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
transport.close();
```

with just this 1 line.

```
Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: hey i did as u said but its giving a new exception like this:   `java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?`

Comment: Just copy and paste your code my netbeans, used my gmail account and worked. Do you have connection to SMTP.gmail.com thorough port 587? (firewall blocking?)

Comment: when a ping smtp.gmail.com i am getting reply that means its connected on my pc na??

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question which has the stacktrace

Comment: Check the answer above, modify source and test.

Comment: hey i changed the code as u said now see the new stack trace edited in the above question.

Comment: I think you don't run the same code, just run the code and works. Remove mail.smtp.ssl.enable property and add tls, then use Transport.send. that is all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51244/discussion-between-user3349720-and-jdiver)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the working Gmail example to copy.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail)